# Using tidyverse to sort data based on timepoint and criteria

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have given up on my code and would hear if anyone had a suggestion as how to get the results I am seeking.
I have a dataframe consisting of three variables: date_time, ID, and x. The “x” column is a recording of a variable x that occurs every 5 minutes. ID indicate what is being recorded. See a piece of the dataframe below.

From this dataframe I would like to calculate a new dataframe consisting of the following columns (there should be a row for each measurement):

1. “ID”.
2. “Measurement”. This column should tell what number measurement this was of a given ID. A “measurement” is defined as a day and night (24h). A measurement starts at 23:00:00 and then runs until 23:00:00 the next day. Recordings however starts at random times and the duration of the first measurement is not 24 hours. Furthermore, a measurement is divided into a “day” (7:00:00-22:59:59) and “night” (23:00:00-6:59:59). We need the “day” in the creation of other columns.
3. “Date”. This column should indicate the date the recordings in a measurement was performed. However, for the first hour from 23:00-23:59, the date should be the following day. I unsuccesfully tried to make it the last recording in a given measurement in this format: yyyy.mm.dd hh:mm:ss.
4. “x_4_10_day_time”: This column should indicate the total amount of time (in minutes) x has been between 4-10 (both included) each day.
5. “Day_time_total”: This column should indicate the total amount of time x has been measured in a day. There are missing values in x that should be subtracted. Missing values of x are left blank. For each missing measurement 5 minutes should be subtracted from the total time. Also, some measurements started later than 7:00.
6. “x_4_10_day_pct”. This column should say how many percent of the total day time x was between 4 and 10 (both included).

There are missing values in the data set. E.g. a period of x being below 4, starting at 02:00:00 and ending at 02:25:00 with three missing values in between should be regarded as a period that is below 15 minutes.

```
structure(list(date_time = c("2020.03.02 22:00:17", "2020.03.02 22:05:17", 
                             "2020.03.02 22:10:17", "2020.03.02 22:15:17", "2020.03.02 22:20:17", 
                             "2020.03.02 22:25:17", "2020.03.02 22:30:17", "2020.03.02 22:35:17", 
                             "2020.03.02 22:40:17", "2020.03.02 22:45:17", "2020.03.02 22:50:17", 
                             "2020.03.02 22:55:17", "2020.03.02 23:00:17", "2020.03.02 23:05:17", 
                             "2020.03.02 23:10:17", "2020.03.02 23:15:17", "2020.03.02 23:20:17", 
                             "2020.03.02 23:25:17", "2020.03.02 23:30:17", "2020.03.02 23:35:17", 
                             "2020.03.02 23:40:17", "2020.03.02 23:45:17", "2020.03.02 23:50:17", 
                             "2020.03.02 23:55:17", "2020.03.03 00:00:17", "2020.03.03 00:05:17", 
                             "2020.03.03 00:10:17", "2020.03.03 00:15:17", "2020.03.03 00:20:17", 
                             "2020.03.03 00:25:17", "2020.03.03 00:30:17", "2020.03.03 00:35:17", 
                             "2020.03.03 00:40:17", "2020.03.03 00:45:17", "2020.03.03 00:50:17", 
                             "2020.03.03 00:55:17", "2020.03.03 01:00:17", "2020.03.03 01:05:17", 
                             "2020.03.03 01:10:17", "2020.03.03 01:15:17", "2020.03.03 01:20:17", 
                             "2020.03.03 01:25:17", "2020.03.03 01:30:17", "2020.03.03 01:35:17", 
                             "2020.03.03 01:40:17", "2020.04.03 08:24:32", "2020.04.03 08:29:32", 
                             "2020.04.03 08:34:32", "2020.04.03 08:39:32", "2020.04.03 08:44:32", 
                             "2020.04.03 08:49:32", "2020.04.03 08:54:32", "2020.04.03 08:59:32", 
                             "2020.04.03 09:04:32", "2020.04.03 09:09:32", "2020.04.03 09:14:32", 
                             "2020.04.03 09:19:32", "2020.04.03 09:24:32", "2020.04.03 09:29:32", 
                             "2020.04.03 09:34:32", "2020.04.03 09:39:32", "2020.04.03 09:44:32", 
                             "2020.04.03 09:49:32", "2020.04.03 09:54:32", "2020.04.03 09:59:32", 
                             "2020.04.03 10:04:32"), case = c(12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
                                                              12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
                                                              13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
                                                              13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
                                                              13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
                                                              13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L), x = c("7.55", "4.55", 
                                                                                                             "4.55", "4.55", "4.55", "12", "12", "12", "12", "10", "10", "4.3", 
                                                                                                             "", "", "4.3", "4.3", "4.3", "", "4.3", "12", "12", "12", "2", 
                                                                                                             "12", "12", "12", "7.55", "4.55", "4.55", "4.55", "4.55", "6", 
                                                                                                             "6", "7", "7", "", "8", "3", "3", "2", "2", "", "3", "6", "7", 
                                                                                                             "12", "12", "2", "12", "10", "10", "4.3", "4.3", "4.3", "4.3", 
                                                                                                             "4.3", "4.3", "4.3", "4.3", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", 
                                                                                                             "12")), row.names = c(NA, 66L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please break your question down into small pieces and post them with minimum reproducible examples.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Summing columns based on criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64293616/summing-columns-based-on-criteria)