# Summing columns based on criteria

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe consisting of three columns: x, ID and date_time.
The “x” column is a recording of a variable x, ID indicate what is being recorded, while date_time indicates when. See a piece of the dataframe below.

From this dataframe I would like to calculate a new dataframe that has seven columns: "Measurement", "ID" and "Date", “x_4_10_day”, “Day_total”, “x_4_10_night”, “Night_total”.

1. “Measurement”. This column should tell what number measurement this was of a given ID. A measurement starts at 23:00:00 and then runs until 22:59:59 the next day. A measurement however starts at random times and the duration of the first measurement is thus not 24 hours. Neither is the last measurement 24 hours.
2. “ID”. Indicate the ID of a given measurement
3. “Date”. This column should show the date of the last recording in a given measurement in this format: yyyy.mm.dd.
4. “x_4_10_day”: A measurement is divided into a day (7:00:00-22:59:59) and a night (23:00:00-6:59:59). This column should indicate the total amount of time (in minutes) x has been between 4-10 (both included) each day in a given measurement. A recording of x between 4-10 can be regarded as x being between 4-10 for 5 minutes, as there is 5 minutes between each recording.
5. “Day_total”: This column should indicate the total amount of time (in minutes) x has been measured in a day. There are missing values in x that should be subtracted. Missing values of x are left blank. For each missing measurement 5 minutes should be subtracted from the total time. Also, some measurements started later than 7:00.
6. “x_4_10_night”: This column should indicate the total amount of time (in minutes) x has been between 4-10 (both included) each night in a given measurement.
7. “Night_total”: This column should indicate the total amount of time (in minutes) x has been measured in a night. There are missing values in x that should be subtracted. Missing values of x are left blank. For each missing measurement 5 minutes should be subtracted from the total time.

There should be a row for every unique measurement. So far I have a code that returns the columns: "Measurement", "ID" and "Date” correctly:

```
df1$mydate = as.Date(df1$date_time, format = "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S")
df1$tm <- as.numeric(df1$date_time)
df1$dts <- 86400*as.numeric(df1$mydate)
df2 <- df1 %>% 
group_by(ID,mydate) %>% 
transform(date = case_when(((dts-3600)<tm & tm<(dts+82800)) ~paste0(mydate), ((dts+82800)<=tm) ~paste0(mydate+1) )) %>% 
select(ID,date) %>%   
unique() %>% 
group_by(ID) %>% 
mutate(measurement = row_number())
```

however I don’t know how to do the last ones.

Here’s an expected output:

```
dummy_output <- read.table(header=TRUE, text ="
                     ID Date        Measurement x_4_10_day Day_total x_4_10_night Night_total
                     12 2020.03.02  1           30         40        0            0
                     12 2020.03.03  2           0          0         45           75
                     13 2020.05.09  1           90         90        0            0
")
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated, thanks!

And here's the data:

```
structure(list(date_time = c("2020.03.02 22:00:17", "2020.03.02 22:05:17", 
"2020.03.02 22:10:17", "2020.03.02 22:35:17", "2020.03.02 22:40:17", 
"2020.03.02 22:45:17", "2020.03.02 22:50:17", "2020.03.02 22:55:17", 
"2020.03.02 23:00:17", "2020.03.02 23:05:17", "2020.03.02 23:10:17", 
"2020.03.02 23:15:17", "2020.03.02 23:20:17", "2020.03.02 23:25:17", 
"2020.03.02 23:30:17", "2020.03.02 23:35:17", "2020.03.02 23:40:17", 
"2020.03.02 23:45:17", "2020.03.02 23:50:17", "2020.03.02 23:55:17", 
"2020.03.03 00:00:17", "2020.03.03 00:55:17", "2020.03.03 01:00:17", 
"2020.03.03 01:05:17", "2020.03.03 01:10:17", "2020.03.03 01:15:17", 
"2020.03.03 01:20:17", "2020.03.03 01:25:17", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", 
"2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", 
"2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", 
"2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", 
"2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", 
"2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", 
"2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32"), id = c(12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L), x = c("7.55", "4.55", "4.55", "12", 
"12", "10", "10", "4.3", "", "", "4.3", "4.3", "4.3", "", "4.3", 
"12", "12", "12", "2", "12", "12", "", "8", "3", "3", "2", "2", 
"", "12", "10", "10", "4.3", "4.3", "4.3", "4.3", "4.3", "4.3", 
"4.3", "4.3", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12")), row.names = c(NA, 
46L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Yes, of course! Thanks for letting me know that I had forgot.

Comment: @Magnus, with the sample data provided, I am unable to understand what `x` is?

Comment: Sorry AnilGoyal and @YBS, you're right, the data frame provided was incomplete. I have provided an updated data frame.

Comment: So! Do you mean your column 4 will have difference of first and last value time, in minutes, based on two conditions 1. X between given values and 2. Time should be of day? Am i correct?

Comment: Also what do you mean by missing values in col x? Do you mean `NA`?

Comment: Yes AnilGoyal, that is what I mean. Yes, missing values is NA. Thanks for helping clariying my question!

Comment: @YBS, I have edited the text and tried to make criteria #4 more clear... Not sure I succeceded though?

Comment: @AnilGoyal, sorry, to hear that

Comment: Ok.  Let me try again.  On the top if it your problem doesn't seem complicated, but probably i m not getting it properly

Comment: Just tell me one more thing, can you `x` range between 4 to 10 more than once in any given day/night?  Like it may exceed 10 then come back within range and again probably increase or decrease beyond the limits.

Comment: @AnilGoyal, yes x goes up and down and it is the total time it has been between 4 and 10 I'm interested in. Each recording of x is not in any way depended on previous or later recordings.

Comment: Yes, @YBS, I agree, criteria #4 was not well worded. What I was trying to say was, that timepoints with no recording of x (x=NA), should not be included in the total Day_total nor in the x_4_10_day columns. For ID 12 (03-03-20), it should therefore be 75 for "night_total" and 25 for "x_4_10_night". Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: "xmint = ifelse(is.na(xn),0,5 ))", should do it, as you have already identified.

Comment: @Magnus, are all your measurements fixed at `5 min` interval?

Comment: @AnilGoyal, For each unique ID, recordings of x are fixed at 5 min intervals, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added `id=14` with only night values to your dataframe.  Perhaps this is what you are looking for.  Please note that your expected values do not comply with your requirements fully.

```
df11 <- structure(list(date_time = c("2020.03.02 22:00:17", "2020.03.02 22:05:17", 
                             "2020.03.02 22:10:17", "2020.03.02 22:35:17", "2020.03.02 22:40:17", 
                             "2020.03.02 22:45:17", "2020.03.02 22:50:17", "2020.03.02 22:55:17", 
                             "2020.03.02 23:00:17", "2020.03.02 23:05:17", "2020.03.02 23:10:17", 
                             "2020.03.02 23:15:17", "2020.03.02 23:20:17", "2020.03.02 23:25:17", 
                             "2020.03.02 23:30:17", "2020.03.02 23:35:17", "2020.03.02 23:40:17", 
                             "2020.03.02 23:45:17", "2020.03.02 23:50:17", "2020.03.02 23:55:17", 
                             "2020.03.03 00:00:17", "2020.03.03 00:55:17", "2020.03.03 01:00:17", 
                             "2020.03.03 01:05:17", "2020.03.03 01:10:17", "2020.03.03 01:15:17", 
                             "2020.03.03 01:20:17", "2020.03.03 01:25:17", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", 
                             "2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", 
                             "2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", 
                             "2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", 
                             "2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", 
                             "2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", 
                             "2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", 
                             "2020.03.02 23:45:17", "2020.03.02 23:50:17", "2020.03.02 23:55:17", 
                             "2020.03.03 00:00:17", "2020.03.03 00:55:17", "2020.03.03 01:00:17" 
                             ), 
                      x = c("7.55", "4.55", "4.55", "12", 
                            "12", "10", "10", "4.3", "", "", "4.3", "4.3", "4.3", "", "4.3", 
                            "12", "12", "12", "2", "12", "12", "", "8", "3", "3", "2", "2", 
                            "", "12", "10", "10", "4.3", "4.3", "4.3", "4.3", "4.3", "4.3", 
                            "4.3", "4.3", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12",
                            "12", "10", "10", "4.3", "4.3", "4.3"),
               id = c(12L, 12L, 
                      12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
                      12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
                      13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
                      13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L)), 
               row.names = c(NA, 52L), class = "data.frame")

df11$xn <- as.numeric(df11$x)
df1 <- df11 %>% transform(xmin = ifelse((xn<4 | xn>10 | is.na(xn)),0,5 ),
                          xmint = ifelse(is.na(xn),-5,5 ))
df1$dateTime = as_datetime(df1$date_time, format = "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S")
df1$mydate = as.Date(df1$date_time, format = "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S")

df1$tm <- as.numeric(df1$dateTime)
df1$dts <- 86400*as.numeric(df1$mydate)

df2 <- df1 %>% group_by(id,mydate) %>% 
         transform(date = case_when(((dts-3600)<tm & tm<(dts+82800) )~paste0(mydate),((dts+82800)<=tm)~paste0(mydate+1) )) %>%
         transform(dayrnight = ifelse((tm>=(dts+25200) & tm<(dts+82800) ),'day','night' ) ) %>% 
         group_by(id,date,dayrnight) %>% 
         dplyr::summarise(x_4_10 = sum(xmin), total = sum(xmint)) %>% 
         pivot_wider(id_cols = c(id,date), names_from = dayrnight, values_from = c("x_4_10", "total")) %>% 
         mutate_if(is.numeric , replace_na, replace = 0) %>% 
         group_by(id) %>% mutate(measurement = row_number()) %>% 
         select(id,date,measurement,x_4_10_day,total_day,x_4_10_night,total_night)

> df2
# A tibble: 4 x 7
# Groups:   id [3]
     id date       measurement x_4_10_day total_day x_4_10_night total_night
  <int> <chr>            <int>      <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
1    12 2020-03-02           1         30        40            0           0
2    12 2020-03-03           2          0         0           25          50
3    13 2020-05-09           1         50        90            0           0
4    14 2020-03-03           1          0         0           25          30
```

Comment: The solution is correct given the situation that measurements take place every 5 min.  But these are at random times as specified by Magnus.

Comment: @YBS, I think the code works perfectly. Just have to double check with some more of my data. I have however changed "xmint = ifelse(is.na(xn),-5,5 ))" to  "xmint = ifelse(is.na(xn),0,5 ))". Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It took me some time but probably you want this

sample data (changed a bit as date/time in `13` were all same

```
df <- structure(list(date_time = c("2020.03.02 22:00:17", "2020.03.02 22:05:17", 
                             "2020.03.02 22:10:17", "2020.03.02 22:35:17", "2020.03.02 22:40:17", 
                             "2020.03.02 22:45:17", "2020.03.02 22:50:17", "2020.03.02 22:55:17", 
                             "2020.03.02 23:00:17", "2020.03.02 23:05:17", "2020.03.02 23:10:17", 
                             "2020.03.02 23:15:17", "2020.03.02 23:20:17", "2020.03.02 23:25:17", 
                             "2020.03.02 23:30:17", "2020.03.02 23:35:17", "2020.03.02 23:40:17", 
                             "2020.03.02 23:45:17", "2020.03.02 23:50:17", "2020.03.02 23:55:17", 
                             "2020.03.03 00:00:17", "2020.03.03 00:55:17", "2020.03.03 01:00:17", 
                             "2020.03.03 01:05:17", "2020.03.03 01:10:17", "2020.03.03 01:15:17", 
                             "2020.03.03 01:20:17", "2020.03.03 01:25:17", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", 
                             "2020.05.09 08:44:32", "2020.05.09 08:49:32", "2020.05.09 08:54:32", 
                             "2020.05.09 08:59:32", "2020.05.09 09:39:32", "2020.05.09 09:44:32", 
                             "2020.05.09 09:49:32", "2020.05.09 09:59:32", "2020.05.09 10:39:32", 
                             "2020.05.09 11:39:32", "2020.05.09 12:39:32", "2020.05.09 13:39:32", 
                             "2020.05.09 14:39:32", "2020.05.09 15:39:32", "2020.05.09 16:39:32", 
                             "2020.05.09 17:39:32", "2020.05.09 18:39:32"), id = c(12L, 12L, 
                                                                                   12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
                                                                                   12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
                                                                                   13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
                                                                                   13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L), x = c("7.55", "4.55", "4.55", "12", 
                                                                                                                   "12", "10", "10", "4.3", "", "", "4.3", "4.3", "4.3", "", "4.3", 
                                                                                                                   "12", "12", "12", "2", "12", "12", "", "8", "3", "3", "2", "2", 
                                                                                                                   "", "12", "10", "10", "4.3", "4.3", "4.3", "4.3", "4.3", "4.3", 
                                                                                                                   "4.3", "4.3", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                           46L), class = "data.frame")
```

Edited Result

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% as_tibble() %>%
  transform(x = as.numeric(x), 
            date_time = as_datetime(date_time),
            id = as.character(id)) %>%
  mutate(d_n = ifelse(hour(date_time)>=7 & hour(date_time)<23, 'day', 'night'),
         Date = as.Date(date_time, format = "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S"),
         valid_m = ifelse(x>=4 & x<= 10, 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(valid_m = ifelse(is.na(valid_m), 0, valid_m)) %>% #valid measurements
  arrange(id, date_time) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(validm_d = as.numeric(lead(date_time)-date_time)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(validm_d)) %>%
  group_by(id, Date, d_n, valid_m) %>%
  summarise(x_tm = sum(validm_d)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = d_n, values_from = x_tm, values_fill =0) %>%
  group_by(id, Date) %>%
  mutate(day_t = sum(day), night_t = sum(night)) %>% 
  filter(valid_m != 0) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(measurement = row_number()) %>%
  select(id, measurement, Date, x_4_10_day =day, x_4_10_total =day_t, 
         x_4_10_night =night, x_4_10_totaln = night_t)
```

desired_result

```
id    measurement Date       x_4_10_day x_4_10_total x_4_10_night x_4_10_totaln
  <chr>       <int> <date>          <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>
1 12              1 2020-03-02         50           60           20            60
2 12              2 2020-03-03          0            0            5            85
3 13              1 2020-05-09        235          600            0             0
```

In this solution I have removed last value of each measurement as I wasn't sure how long that measurement was to be taken.  You can change the code appropriately.  Basically last measurement of 'day' ended 2300 hrs therefore results of first row should have been 17 seconds fewer than those shown.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's much appreciated. When I use your code, I don't get the correct results for x_4_10_day, Day_total, x_4_10_night and Night_total. The numbers get way too high.

Comment: hm, using the data and code you provide I get 60 in first row of column "x_4_10_day" . It should be 40...

Comment: In the data and code you provide now, column "x_4_10_day" is 50, and column "x_4_10_total"  is 60 in the first row. They should however be 30 and 40. In measurement 1, there are 6 recordings of x between 4 and 10 and 8 recordings in total (between 7:00:00 and 22:59:59).

Comment: @Magnus  Now it is giving 50 in first row (5,5,25,5,5,5) for (1,2,3,6,7,8th) values respectively as time difference between 3rd and 4th reading is 25 minutes

Comment: @Magnus, please re-check.

Comment: Time difference between 3rd and 4th reading should be regarded as missing values and these should not be included

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222857/discussion-between-anilgoyal-and-magnus).